# How to conditionally store to a pointer in AVX2

Tags: simd, avx, avx2, avx512

I have to conditionally store the values from my vector register to my double array. Given a `__m256d` and a mask, I want to store the values in my vector to the target array only for those places where the mask value is 1.

I am aware of the `_mm256_maskstore_pd` function but I cannot seem to get it working as intended. The code is as follows -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(){

    auto a = _mm256_set_pd(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
    
    double* pointer = (double*)malloc(16 * sizeof(double));
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        *pointer = 21345;
    }

    __m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x(1);

    _mm256_maskstore_pd(pointer, mask, a);
    std::cout<<pointer[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

According to my understanding, a value of `1.0` should get populated at `pointer[0]` but it remains the same. I suppose I am not completely aware of how the function works.

Could anyone please elaborate on it?

TIA

Comment: Try : `__m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1);` . Mask uses the highest bit.

Comment: Ah I did not know that, so what if I want to set the mask as (1, 0, 1, 0) that is I want to store every other alternate value, it would be just (-1, 0, -1, 0) correct ?

Comment: Yes, see the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmaskmov

Comment: Also, be aware that the `_mm*_set_*` intrinsics take the arguments in big-endian order. They all should have a `_setr_` alternative which uses little-endian order: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=mm256_setr&techs=AVX&ig_expand=6134,6222

Comment: Since you tagged AVX-512, note that AVX-512 `__mask8` and similar types are integer bitmasks, not vectors at all, and are used with different intrinsics.  AVX-512 masked stores are even more efficient than AVX2 masked stores on Intel hardware.  (AVX2 masked stores are quite slow on existing AMD hardware, and none of it supports AVX-512.)

Comment: But upon setting the mask as `__m256i mask = _mm256_set_epi64x(-1, 0, -1, 0);`, the output is `21345  3  0  1`, I dont think this is correct, right ?, like why is it 21345 at the end does not seem right

Comment: Read chtz's comment from 8 mins before yours: the low element of your mask is `0`, so it left `pointer[0]` unmodified.  (And your loop only writes `pointer[0]` repeatedly, not `pointer[i]`, so the 3rd element, element #2, stayed `0.0` the whole time where your mask had another 0.)

Comment: Ah missed that, show more the comments. That makes sense, Thanks a lot